# nltk ngrams >> TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram

I've been reading around for a few hours and seems like every time I solve one error I run into another one.

I'm trying to use nltk to generate various ngrams (unigram / bigram / trigram ...) based on words that are found within a csv (example attached).

Apologies, that this is likely really simple. That said, any help would be appareciated!

```
import re
import os
import csv
from collections import Counter
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk import word_tokenize
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')


cwd = os.getcwd()

ngrams = open(os.path.join(cwd, "combined.csv"),
              "r", encoding="utf8")

with ngrams as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    keywords = [item['Keyword'] for item in reader]
    string = " ".join(keywords)
    # token = nltk.word_tokenize(string)
    unigrams = ngrams(string, 1)
    bigrams = ngrams(string, 2)
    trigrams = ngrams(string, 3)

    print(trigrams)
```

ERROR

```
  File "ngram.py", line 27, in <module>
    unigrams = ngrams(string, 1)
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable
```

combined.csv >>

keyword
'k cups',
'k cup coffee',
'keurig coffee pods',
'coffee pods',
'keurig not dispensing water',
'keurig not pumping water',
'how long do k cups last',
'keurig won t pump water',
'keurig troubleshooting',
'cheap k cups',
'folgers commercial',
'tea k cups',
'keurig water not coming out',

Comment: Did you notice you've tried to call two things `ngrams`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is the you overload `ngrams`. (You use it as file and as ntlk function)

A fix can be:

```
with open(os.path.join(cwd, "combined.csv"),
              "r", encoding="utf8") as ngrams_file
    reader = csv.DictReader(ngrams_file, delimiter=',')
    keywords = [item['Keyword'] for item in reader]
    string = " ".join(keywords)
    # token = nltk.word_tokenize(string)
    unigrams = ngrams(string, 1)
    bigrams = ngrams(string, 2)
    trigrams = ngrams(string, 3)

print(trigrams)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflict between NLTK function name and file descriptor name. You need to change descriptpr name or rewrite `with` construction:

```
with open(os.path.join(cwd, "combined.csv"), "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
    # your operations and ngrams method here
```